# How to design this database table concept?

Tags: database-design

Suppose I have a table `Articles`. An `article` can have only one `topic` attached to it. But it is also possible that article has no `topic`.

1. Should I make `topic` a new column in `Articles` table? OR
2. Should I create a table `topics2articles` and map together a `topic` with `article`?
   (In this case I do not have to add extra column for `Articles` table.

I don't like the 1st solution because then some rows will have `NULL` in them? Or is this reasonable to have `NULL` in this case?

What do you think?

Thanks, Boda Cydo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see any reason for you to make a new table just to avoid having rows with `NULL` in them.

It would make sense to add it to the article table, and probably make it easier to maintain since you wouldn't have to join against another table.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably suggest that if topic has other related data that you should create 2 tables: one for ARTICLE and one for TOPIC with the ARTICLE PK as a foreign key in TOPIC.

Comment: but what if there are two articles with the same topic?

Answer (score 0):

One-to-one relations are generally just an annoyance... Keep them in a single table, as long as row length doesn't become a bottleneck of your application.

Comment: I believe intgr is referring to the number of columns in a row and the width of those columns.

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed out, in case of (1) you will have some NULL rows.
In case of (2) you will have an extra table with 2 indexes. In my opinion, if there is no chance that article will ever have more than 1 topic and a number of articles without topics is not greater than 50-70% of the total number of articles (1) will work better.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the kind of scenario that a pointy haired boss might use to inflict undue pain on you later when they ask that `topic` be used for tagging in a many-to-many fashion.

For that reason, I would go with #2.

If you're *really* confident that it won't turn around and bite you, #1 is a good choice. Avoiding `NULL`s seems like a pretty weak reason not to go with it. It's not clear if you were intending to store them as text or FK's to a topic table, but I'd go with a separate table for topics.

Comment: I am going with a FK to a topic table. Sorry for not mentioning that.